# Best way for SqlConnection inside a loop

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am processing about 24k records totally per day in a windows service, I insert the rows into a database and then I save image compressed in a directory.

Generally, what is the best way for this?

```
using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection())
{
    foreach (var item in collection)
    {
        //do stuff 

        SaveImage(item.filename,item.img);
    }
}
```

or

```
foreach (var item in collection)
{
    using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection())
    {
        //do stuff
    }

    SaveImage(item.filename, item.img);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You might to specify what ***best*** is.  Efficiency, readability, safety, maintainability, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would build the connection outside of the loop. If it were something that were running *forever* my answer would be different, for instance if you were running a web service I would suggest that you open connections for each request (that's super different, but I'm just giving an example). But opening a connection is a resource-intensive task, and it'll just be easier to work off of a single one in a case like this. It really depends on what you're focused on here, as a couple other people have said, but I think a single connection sounds perfectly acceptable. And as I see another commenter said, you could then use transactions to wrap it all up, if that would help you at all.

---

The rest of this stuff isn't meant to answer your question directly, I just think it's worth thinking about given your situation.

You might want to look into the SQL `MERGE` statement, though. It'd be much faster if you could send more than one record to SQL at a time. You'd still, of course, have to save your images separately, but this could at least make the SQL aspect faster. Of course you can also do that with the `INSERT` statement, but that depends on whether every single new record you're passing is actually new, or if it'll violate unique keys.

You could also look into the [TPL Dataflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603(v=vs.110).aspx) because it has some useful classes for doing multiple operations concurrently and in batches that might make your insert way faster as well. Remember, though, that a single connection is sometimes not the best at handling concurrent requests. But if you were splitting your data into sets of 100 (remember that 2100 is the maximum number of query parameters per `SqlCommand`, so just take that divided by however many you need and subtract a margin of error), I'd probably say just go with creating the connection for each one.

I know this is way more than what you asked for, but I work with situations like this a lot so I thought I'd share some of what I've picked up along the way.

Comment: Just came across this regarding MERGE https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/

Answer (score 0):

First solution if you are using the connection on every loop since it does not get recreated each loop.

Creating connections it a time consuming procedure

Also I would recommend to use a single [transaction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188929.aspx) if possible for all query's

Comment: "Creating connections it a time consuming procedure" Actually no it isn't if you are connecting to the same place over and over. ADO uses a Connection Pool and will keep the connection open for a little bit after you close it to allow other parts to re-use the connection.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Is that not an implementation detail that isn't guaranteed on all platforms?

Comment: @itsme86 It is guaranteed [on all `SqlConnection` objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.110).aspx). For other `DbConnection` derived classes it is up to the implementer of the class, but the .NET [OLE DB, ODBC, and OracleClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254502(v=vs.110).aspx) can support it if it is set up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of factors here but in most cases I would suggest opening/closing a connection WITHIN the loop and doing a little as needed to work with the database during that connection.

You will need a lot of error handling but it makes it easier to continue your loop for more records if something fails during the body of the connection or image processing.

Answer (score 0):

You first approach will skip the entire process if the connection breaks.

Your second approach is creating a new connection for on EACH loop which dreally drags down the performance.

What you could do is perform it in batches (say 50).

```
var batchSize = 50;

for(int i = 0; i<collection.Count ; i+=batchSize)
{
     using (var cnn = new SqlConnection())
     {
      int j = 0
      foreach (var item in collection.Skip(i))
      {
        if(j++ == batchSize) continue;

         //do stuff     
         SaveImage(item.filename,item.img);     
      }
     }
}
```

Here, you are creating a connection once every 50 rows in your data. You can adjust this to your will to optimize performance vs reliability.